# Does MonoDevelop support Android development using VB.NET?

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have read and read about this and I am still confused. We need to port a VB.NET library to something that will run on Android. We are trying to avoid switching to C# because all our apps that rely on the library are in VB.NET.

I was investigating options and I came across MonoDevelop (or it seems to be called Xamarin Studio now), and Xamarin.Android. It appears that with Xamarin Studio has support for VB.NET, but with Xamarin.Android installed only the C# project types seem to include Android projects.

I understood that VB.NET and C# compile to ostensibly the same intermediate code, so is it foolish to assume that there should also be options for VB.NET projects to work with Android projects? The development environment already supports VB.NET and C# compilation for other project types.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: You shouldn't *assume* that, no - VB.NET requires some additional libraries which may not have been ported for use on Android yet. On the other hand, I'm not saying that it definitely *isn't* supported either. I've got Xamarin Studio 4.0.10 installed, and I don't get any VB Android options either... and the Xamarin website is *very* C#-focused.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Xamarin, but I agree with Jon. It seems very C# focused, and I've searched for a while about VB.NET, and it doesn't show positive results. Already compiled VB.NET DLLs probably won't work, because some VB.NET base assemblies are not included in Xamarin. If I were you, I'd try using tools that convert VB to C#.

Comment: Xamarin supports C# and has some support F#.  VB.NET is not supported.